# How to correctly remove a transitive dependency from a maven repo with gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, dependency-management

I'm getting the following error when building my project:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

As I understand it this is because I have multiple libraries that depend on slf4j. The dependencies in my build.gradle file are:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:some-sdk')
    compile files('libs/some-library.jar')
    compile 'com.some-module:some-artifact:X.X.X'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3'
}
```

I know that the logback-android-classic dependency is the problem because it does depend on slf4j and if I comment that out my project builds fine. According to other sources I've found this is usually solved by excluding the transitive dependency like so:

```
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3') {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
```

However even after I clean and rebuild I'm still getting the error.

UPDATE:
Running dependencyInsight looking for slf4j as dmahapatro suggested returned no results:

```
$ gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency slf4j --configuration compile
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':main:compile'
```

My full dependency tree is:

```
+--- project :stripe
+--- project :apptentive-android-sdk
+--- project :numberpicker
+--- project :switch-backport
+--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3
+--- org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.2.4.Final
+--- org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0
+--- com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0
+--- com.pusher:pusher-java-client:0.3.1
\--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3
     +--- com.github.tony19:apktool-lib:1.4.4-3
     |    \--- com.google.android:android:2.1_r1
     |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
     |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
     |         |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
     |         |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
     |         |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
     |         +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
     |         +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
     |         \--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
     \--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-3
```

Update 2:

I have narrowed the conflict down to the logback-android-classic library and a local jar (Unfortunately I can't edit this jar directly due to licensing issues). Excluding either of these resolves the conflict, and an empty generic test app with only these two dependencies will have the conflict. I have verified that the local jar contains org.slf4j but because of the aforementioned licensing issues, I can't do much about that. So I'm left with my only option being to exclude slf4j from logback-android-classic. Given that the dependency tree doesn't actually show slf4j as a dependency of logback-android-classic, and given that adding

```
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3') {
            exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
```

has not resolved the issue, how can I exclude the slf4j dependency from logback-android-classic?

Final Update:
Ultimately this was resolved by working with the owners of the local jar I was using to get logback removed from that. I doubt that this is a particularly useful answer for future visitors, but wanted to include it for the sake of completion.

Comment: run `dependencyInsight` to see from where `slf4j` is being pulled. `gradle -p dependencyInsight --dependency slf4j --configuration compile`. This will make things clear.

Comment: I'm getting "Configuration with name 'compile' not found." Which I know is usually caused by missing build.gradle files but I've verified that they all exist. Any tips? Otherwise I suppose this may be it's own question.

Comment: I meant `-q` instead of `-p`. My bad. `gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency slf4j --configuration compile`

Comment: I'd gathered that the -p didn't make sense there. Still getting the "Configuration with name 'compile' not found." error.

Comment: Is this a multi project build? Can the app be shared in github or at least the build.gradle file in a Gist?

Comment: Yes it is a multi project build. I can't share my actual project, but I've created a small test project that reproduces my symptoms. The build.gradle is here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1af96ce7abe7d6094d2a

Comment: Ok, so I think I was being dense. I was running that command at the root project, not my main project. When I run it for my main project it does find the compile configuration, but doesn't find slf4j. "No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':main:compile'"

Comment: "I've created a small test project that reproduces my symptoms" -- upload it somewhere. The `build.gradle` file you put in a gist is uninformative, as the only dependency it lists is to a `HelloLibrary` module that we don't have. Create a clean Android Gradle project, with no dependencies. Add in those dependencies one at a time, until either the error occurs, or you get all your dependencies. In the latter case, figure out what is different between the test project and your real one. Also, you might try `0.12.2` for the Gradle for Android plugin, in case this is some bug that was fixed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added a note in the question, the conflict I'm seeing involves a library that I can't upload because of licensing issues. But it is just a local jar which directly contains org.slf4j. I followed your advice of creating a clean project, and adding only the local jar and the logback-android-classic library as dependencies creates the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in my "build.gradle" to remove the transitive dependency issue of "slf4j". This is the way to exclude the dependency so that is doesn't get loaded transitively. And load the conflicting libraries explicitly by mentioning it in the "compile group" statements. Thought it may help you.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jcl-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jcl-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
}

compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: log4j2Version
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: log4j2Version
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: slf4jToLog4jVersion
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and it didn't appear to have any effect, still getting the same error as above. It's possible I'm implementing this wrong, I assume the compile statements go in my dependencies block, but not entirely sure where the configurations block would go. I've tried it at the base level of my build.gradle and inside the android{} block.

Comment: Yes, compile statements will go in dependencies block and configurations block will exist at the same level as dependencies level.